# How to distill bert+crf knowledge to a smaller network for sequence labeling

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, crf

I'm using BERT-BILSTM-CRF model for sequence labeling. What I want now is to distill the heavy model to a much smaller one like lstm-crf. After surveying relevant papers, I found almost all the solution are based on softmax output instead of crf output. Is there is a solution for crf-output distillation?